# search form to search a DB on another server

Tags: php, mysql

I have never needed to do this before, but I am developing an application which will be installed to a users website - but it will need to query data held in a database stored on the application's server.

Server A (client - domian: www.example.com)

Server B (application).

There will be a form on Server A (a Search form) which POSTS search data to the Server B (application) along with some information about Server A (domain, IP).

Server B handler will:-

1.) Check if Server A is an actual client  (i.e. is domain (www.example.com) in the allowed domains list and does the request come from the IP of Server A.

2.) If 1.) is TRUE, it will process the request, and return a response being the results of the query.

I can't seem to find anything on Google or this site where someone wants to do this? I could be searching for the wrong thing though.

Also, would there be any limits on the size of the array that is returned back to Server A??

I do not want to grant DB access to the user - unless this is the only solution (i.e. create a new mysql DB user with READ only capability upon activation of the application).??

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IF you're posting data to server b (the db host) then the query will be run locally on that server.

What you need is some script that can handle your post OR if you want to connect to the db from server A and also handle the post i server A then you have to give that server the right to connect to the db-server.

So then thing you need to do is to write a script on the server B that will handle the post.

My guess is that you're better of giving server A (proper)access rights to the db on server B.

Comment: So assuming I write the script on server B to handle the post, but the query is only run on server B if the request is valid. The response to server A would then be handled in the HTTP response (I think)

Comment: Well what is the point of sending a response to server a? It's the browser that you want to send information to, isn't it?

Comment: Server A would take the response and process data into it's own DB (a subset of the main DB).

Comment: Then it seems to me that you're better of giving server a rights to access the DB on server B, if you find my answer correct or helpfull please consider accepting it. :)